# Does Direct Line App Service extension work on Azure Linux App Service?

Tags: azure-web-app-service, botframework, direct-line-botframework, azure-linux

I am working in project which uses Bot Framework, and We are implementing DirectLine with websockets connection. For this, we are using Direct Line App Service extension. We are following these steps: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/bot-service/bot-service-channel-directline-extension-net-bot?view=azure-bot-service-4.0.

When We publish the project from VS2022 on an Azure Windows App Service, it works correctly, but when we publish it on Linux, the route that finishes with "/.bot" returns 404 not found response.

We don't find anything about this problem on internet.

Do we need to configure anything else for it works on Linux App Service?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Linux App Services do not currently support extensions of any kind, so the Direct Line Extension is not currently supported on a Linux App Service. You can run the bot and use standard Direct Line on Linux, but if you require the network isolation offered by the extension, you will need to use the Windows App Service.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. So another question: Could we use websockets stream to receive activities without Direct Line Extension on Linux App Service?

Comment: It might be possible. Linux App Services do support websockets.